# ios swift dismiss keyboard when PMCalendar tapped or open

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

When I tapped on [PMCalendar](https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar) view my calendar open but my keyboard not dismiss. [image]

I have tried `self.view.endEditing(true)`

Answer (score 0):

[Try  textField.resignFirstResponder()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621097-resignfirstresponder)

Comment: not worked for me , I have also put some delay also. Thanks for reply